# Syslog grows quickly - gnome-session

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, syslog

Good afternoon,

This is a newbie question: I'm facing an issue with */var/log/syslog*... it's growing rapidly and the HD runs out of memory. 
These are the latest logs for example:

```
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      s18615199.onlinehome-server.com
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      163.53.196.238
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      ip-112-26.4vendeta.com
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      zanagaqwe2.example.com
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      ip196.ip-51-83-216.eu
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      163.53.196.238
May 27 16:20:58 ... gnome-session[1902]: 27/05/2020 16:20:58      ip-112-26.4vendeta.com
```

and I don't know what these logs refer to (smth related to gnome). It's an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I'd appreciate any hint. Thanks in advance.